# Where is Android view mode in Android Strudio 0.8.2

Tags: android, android-studio

I can't see "Android" line inside my menu like screenshot(this screenshot from http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hu4U8XKmJGA).

[image]

My Android Studio version 0.8.2, OS Linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is being implemented but isn't released yet. It's something that Google was showing in the demo as a preview of a future feature. I don't have a bug you can look at to track the progress of it, and the feature isn't yet even checked into source control.

Comment: Thanks. I suspect that having same version on video and my computer is sufficient condition.

Comment: He wasn't running the real 0.8.2 ;)